# DNS Help (CNAMEs and A Records)

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record

I'm trying to set up my DNS properly so that I can have hosting through [PHPFog](http://phpfog.com/) and email services using [MailGun](https://mailgun.net/). PHPFog has us redirect the naked domain to the www and then use a CNAME to point the www to [PHPFog](http://docs.phpfog.com/customize/custom-domain-names) and mailgun [provides the MX records to use](http://documentation.mailgun.net/user_manual.html). The problem I'm having is that I have no A record set up on [Hover](http://www.hover.com) because when I do, the CNAME no longer works (?), or at least it seems that way because I am no longer seeing my site from PHPFog, I'm seeing a Hover landing page. I know all the records I need, I just can't seem to get them to play nicely together. I've been told Amazon's Route 53 should be able to solve my problem, but I haven't yet figured out how. I just need to have hosting at PHPFog and email services through MailGun.

As you can probably tell, I have only a very limited understanding of DNS, so forgive me if this is a silly question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot mix a CNAME and any other "common" record for the same name. That's by specification. Wikipedia will tell you more about [the CNAME restrictions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME#Restrictions).

You solution here would probably look like:

```
example.com. MX 10 smtp1.example.com.
example.com. MX 20 smtp2.example.com.
example.com. A 4.3.2.1
www.example.com. CNAME example.com.
smtp1.example.com. A 1.2.3.4
smtp2.example.com. A 5.6.7.8
```

Where `1.2.3.4` is the IP address for your mail delivery server, `smtp2` of IP `5.6.7.8` is a hypothetical backup mail delivery server (get one, get rid of the associated 2 lines if you don't care), `4.3.2.1` is the IP for your web server.

Answer (score 0):

Handling the redirect of `www.example.com` can be done with a simple `CNAME` record.   PHPFog directions should include the correct target for the `CNAME`.  You won't be able to receive mail addressed to the `www` sub-domain.

```
www.example.com.  IN  CNAME  phpfog.example.net
```

Mail servers are located by an `MX` record.  Mailgun should provide a name for the mail server to target.  I've included SPF records which you may want to include. If they provide multiple host names add more `MX` records. Some servers don't support the SPF record type, in which case SPF will use the `TXT` record.

```
example.com. IN  MX 10  mailgun.example.net
                 TXT    'v=spf1 MX -all'
                 SPF    'v=spf1 MX -all'
```

Your domain does not need an IP address, and shouldn't have one unless you have a server with a static address.  However, this means your web site will only be available using the `www` sub-domain.  Some (most?) browsers will handle this for users who don't include the `www.` portion of the name.  If you do have a server, it can run a lightweight web server which redirects all traffic to the `www` sub-domain.

You will also need NS records for your domain, but those should already be configured.